# Multiply methods to property in Swift

Tags: swift, customization, extension-methods

Greeting, Everyone!
I'm wondering how implement ability to multiply methods associated to certain class

For example I've got custom class of UITextField
and I want to configurate it any way I need.
How can I handle it to get result kinda `myTextField.configure().addSomeExtraFeatures().andOneMoreMethod()`
like in RxSwift `viewModel.fetch().rx.asObservable.bind(to: ...`

Can anyone show me some direction to resolving? :) Any clue, please 
Even how properly call this process will be useful

Comment: You can return `self` in these methods for chain them. That's what does Alamofire for instance (https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/d9259d107a9539c0e94dee500bfe9b98a004d91d/Source/ResponseSerialization.swift#L601) RxSwift returns something to on `bind(to:)` https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/78f2dd64f12c09b5bc31ef719e55b1a4c4da0d3d/RxRelay/Observable%2BBind.swift etc.

Answer (score 1):

Return self in every function and use @discardableResult attribute so no need to care about the return.
For more about @discardableResult: https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/discardableresult/

Your UITextField custom class should be like this.

```
class CustomTextField: UITextField {
    
    @discardableResult
    func configure() -> Self {
        // Do your code here
        return self
    }
    
    @discardableResult
    func addSomeExtraFeatures() -> Self {
        // Do your code here
        return self
    }
    
    @discardableResult
    func andOneMoreMethod() -> Self {
        // Do your code here
        return self
    }
}
```

Usage:

Create an instance of CustomTextField and call function.

```
let customTextField: CustomTextField = CustomTextField()

customTextField.configure().addSomeExtraFeatures()
```

Comment: It’s not possible it might be some issue in your code please check.

Comment: yeah, problem was that I added setup method in `viewWillLayout` cause in `.configure()` was some constraint and Rect. Now I solved it when changed location to `viewDidLoad`. Thanks a lot.